# CMake library configuration file is linking against both debug and release version of library

Tags: c++, cmake, find-package

I've edited the `CMakeFileLists.txt` (and project structure) of [CNPY](https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy) library to automatically generate a `cnpy-config.cmake` file for importing into my project.

Everything works fine: the library is compiled and `.lib`, `.dll`, `.cmake` files are correctly generated and installed (I've used `Debug` and `Release` configurations).

In particular, three configuration files are produced in `cmake` folder: `cnpy-config.cmake`, `cnpy-config-debug.cmake`, cnpy-config-release.cmake`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.25 FATAL_ERROR)

if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

project(CNPY VERSION 1.0.0)
if(NOT CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX)
  set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
endif()
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# option(ENABLE_STATIC "Build static (.a) library" OFF)

find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

add_library(cnpy SHARED)
    target_sources(cnpy PRIVATE src/cnpy.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(cnpy ZLIB::ZLIB)
    target_include_directories(cnpy PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>)
    target_compile_features(cnpy PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
    install(
        TARGETS cnpy
        EXPORT cnpy_export
        INCLUDES DESTINATION include
    )

    # Install directories
    install (
        DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/
        DESTINATION include
    )

# Export configuration file
install(EXPORT cnpy_export
        FILE cnpy-config.cmake
        NAMESPACE cnpy::
        # This is always relative to ${CMAKE_PREFIX_INSTALL}
        DESTINATION cmake
)
```

Now I have my project (very basic right now) that uses `cnpy`:

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(MyProject)

message("Current configuration: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package(CNPY REQUIRED) 

add_executable(MyExe)
target_sources(MyExe PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyExe PRIVATE cnpy::cnpy)
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include<cnpy.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    std::string filename("C:\\some\\path\\array.npy");
#ifdef NDEBUG
    printf("I'm in Release mode\n");
#else
    printf("I'm in Debug mode\n");
#endif

    auto arr = cnpy::npy_load(filename);

    std::cout << "Read array of " << arr.as_vec<float>().size() << std::endl;
}
```

Everything works fine. BUT: `main.exe` requires **both** `cnpy.dll` and `cnpyd.dll`, no matter whether I'm building in `Release` or `Debug` mode.

Digging into `cnpy-config.cmake`, I noticed the following part of code, that includes ALWAYS both `*-debug.cmake` and `*-release.cmake` files.

```
[...]
file(GLOB _cmake_config_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cnpy-config-*.cmake")
foreach(_cmake_config_file IN LISTS _cmake_config_files)
  include("${_cmake_config_file}")
endforeach()
unset(_cmake_config_file)
unset(_cmake_config_files)
[...]
```

The content of the two files follow for clarity:

```
# cnpy-config-release.cmake
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "Release".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "cnpy::cnpy" for configuration "Release"
set_property(TARGET cnpy::cnpy APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(cnpy::cnpy PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/cnpy.lib"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/cnpy.dll"
  )

list(APPEND _cmake_import_check_targets cnpy::cnpy )
list(APPEND _cmake_import_check_files_for_cnpy::cnpy "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/cnpy.lib" "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/cnpy.dll" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)




# cnpy-config-debug.cmake
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "Debug".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "cnpy::cnpy" for configuration "Debug"
set_property(TARGET cnpy::cnpy APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG)
set_target_properties(cnpy::cnpy PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/cnpyd.lib"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/cnpyd.dll"
  )

list(APPEND _cmake_import_check_targets cnpy::cnpy )
list(APPEND _cmake_import_check_files_for_cnpy::cnpy "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/cnpyd.lib" "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/cnpyd.dll" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
```

As far as I understand (I'm not a CMake expert TBH), the two debug and release versions of the library are always included.

Apart from a *hack* solution of manually editing the master configuration file to check upon configuration, such reported below (I don't like this solution), is there any solution to **automatically** generate a configuration file that can **discern** configurations, or help the *as is* (already generated) configuration file to discern the configuration?

```
IF (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES Debug)
   include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cnpy-config-debug.cmake")
ELSE()
   include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cnpy-config-release.cmake")
ENDIF()
```

Please, I've googled a lot of answers (inside and outside SO), but I've not got anything for this case in particular: If I was missing something and this is a duplicate, I'm really sorry.

Comment: Content of `cnpy-config-release.cmake` and `cnpy-config-debug.cmake` looks correct: the first one assigns `RELEASE`-suffixed properties, the second one assigns `DEBUG`-suffixed properties. "`main.exe` requires **both** `cnpy.dll` and `cnpyd.dll`" - How exactly this requirement is expressed? Do you get any error. or something else? Which [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) do you use when configure your projects? MinGW?